# Product of two non differentiable functions.

Tags: limits, derivatives

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=a$ , $f(x), g(x)$ is continuous at x=a and $f(a)=g(a)=0$ then $f(x).g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$.

I was trying prove or disprove this statement, can anyone give me hint or clue to solve this.

Comment: Hint: for which positive values of the real parameter $k$ is $f_k:x\mapsto|x|^k$ differentiable at $0$? Note also that $f_k^2=f_{2k}$.

Comment: Differentiable at x=0 when we don't have any cusp , vertical tangent or sharp corner.

Comment: When k>1 it would be differentiable, because when k>1, in the derivative part $ |x|^{k-1}$ will be zero so approaching from both sides gives us 0.

Comment: Ok, and what happens for $0<k\le1$? (These values are the most interesting, to disprove the statement by a counterexample.)

Comment: For $0 < k \leq 1$ either it was cusp or sharp corner at $x=0$, i don't know this example was correct or not, $f(x) = |x|^{1/2} ,  g(x)=|x|^{1/3}$ both $f(x) , g(x)$ are not differentiable at x=0 and they do continuous at x=0 but their product is still not differentiable i.e $|x|^{5/6} $ which not differentiable at x=0.

Comment: Well done! You can edit your self-answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks alot man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be disproved by an example.

for function $f:x\mapsto |x|^{k}$ where $k$ is positive real, then it would be non-differentiable at $x=0$ if $k \leq 1$ and fortunately $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Consider $f(x) = |x|^{\frac{1}{2}}$ , $g(x) = |x|^{\frac{1}{4}}$ both of these are not differentiable at $x=0$ and continuous, still their product isn't differentiable at $x=0$.